# iPhone Tab bar icon are misaligned - iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have an application that was initially built with iOS 4.0, but which is now iOS 7.0 + only.

I have a tab bar with 4 icons, and they used to be placed appropriately. But now, they are about 10 pixels higher than where they should be. (See images).

**Before**

[image: Tab bar before]

**Now**

[image]

The icons, the text or the nib files have not changed. I don't know where to look. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your image icon size?

Comment: Non-retina: 50 x 50 pixels. Retina: 104 x 104 pixels.

Comment: That is an issue, I guess so. Check this iOS HIG for tabbar icons: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html

Comment: It was the issue all right. I thought I was following the guide, but I wasn't taking the note into account. I'm still thinking in non-retina pixels, and I multiply everything by 2. (The note mention sizes should be divided by 2 for non-retina). If you wrap this up in an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please update your image dimensions according to : [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html)

It has been changed for iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the tabbarItem imageInsets

```
navigationCtroller.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(7,0, -7,0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sure this would have worked, but it would have been a not-so-clean workaround. It really was the size of the artwork that was off.

Comment: please adjust the imageInset.